# NativeModules does not include RNNordicDfu

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, npm

I'm using [react-native-nordic-dfu](https://github.com/manualexSP/react-native-nordic-dfu) in my project, and when I try to use the library, the app crashes with the error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'startDFU' of undefined`.

The error seems to be happening inside the module at `node_modules\react-native-nordic-dfu\index.js`.

Line 2 defines RNNordicDfu with `const { RNNordicDfu } = NativeModules;` but when I logged it out, NativeModules didn't have an RNNordicDfu property. Is there something wrong with the package itself? I'm really at a loss with this one.

I have also tried reinstalling the package to no avail.

```json
"dependencies": {
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "convert-string": "^0.1.0",
    "expo": "~47.0.12",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.17.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.2",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.8",
    "react-native-ble-manager": "^8.6.0",
    "react-native-nordic-dfu": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-quick-base64": "^2.0.5"
  },
```

I'm currently running Node v18.15.0.

Testing on a Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra

Comment: did you clear the Metro cache and rebuild after installing?

Comment: I did. It didn't change the error.

Comment: How about clearing the Android build cache?

Comment: Yeah, I actually pushed my changes and pulled then down to a different computer just to verify there was no cache issue, used gradlew clean, and ran again.
Still getting the same error.

Comment: The tree I've been barking up today is linking. I've tried running `react-native-link react-native-nordic-dfu` as well as manually linking the package and it hasn't appeared in NativeModules.

I don't have any experience creating native modules, but I'm trying to compare it with another module that is working (react-native-ble-manager). There are a lot of differences with how they declare and name themselves, so it's not super straight forward, but I haven't found anything obviously wrong yet.

Comment: Update on this: I have moved away from NPM's react-native-nordic-dfu because that actually points to the old version of the library for some reason. I am now pointing it to the repo linked in my original post. I have tried a few people's forks of this project with no success. I tried to spin up some of their example projects, but so far none of them have worked because they either use super outdated versions of everything, or updated the versions without changing settings that need to be updated when you do that kind of an upgrade.

Comment: Update: I added a log to the module declaration and checked Logcat and this module never even started up. For some reason, React Native doesn't know about it.

Comment: It looks like new versions of RN might need you to actually re run expo build after adding native modules. I'm used to the older versions of RN where you'd just eject rather than pre-building, so that's news to me. I managed to break my dev environment while troubleshooting, so I'm going to fix that first, then try rebuilding with expo. (in my past comments about building I was using either gradle or android studio to build the project.)